# Event handling in UITableViewCell's subviews

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I need to create a tableView with customized UITableViewCell that has three small buttons in their view. Is there any way by which I can trap the click events of Buttons as well as didSelectRow of TableView and decide what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Any subviews of a table view cell will receive events just as if they were placed outside of the table. Just create the `UIButton` objects you need, add them to the table cell's `contentView`, and then make sure to set up any [actions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006779-RH2-SW4) you want to know about.

Comment: would this not interfere with the didSelectRowAtIndex method of UITableView delegate?

Comment: Nope. A touch is only considered to be a row selection if it's received by the cell itself, not any subviews listening for events.